# copy and rename multiple sheets in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to copy a master copy everytime I click a button.

When I put the copy command in the for loop, it produces all 20 worksheets.

However I want to produce a sheet on every click of a button and name 1, 2 ..etc.

I have put the copy command outside the for loop

It does the first sheet perfectly. on the next click I am getting an Error 400.
Any assistance to produce these worksheets and rename them will n

```
    Sub NewSheets()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template")
Set sh = Sheets("Sheets Insert")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

Sheets("Master").Copy After:=sh

For i = 20 To 2 Step -1
'Sheets("Master").Copy After:=sh   
ActiveSheet.Name = i


Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to produce a sheet on every click of a button and name 1, 2 ..etc.

Then don't use a loop at all.  Just make a new sheet on the button click and name the sheet to the proper number (1, 2, 3, etc).  So change your sub to:

```
Sub NewSheets()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template") ' Note that you are never using this...

Set sh = Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' This will be the last sheet in the Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

Sheets("Master").Copy After:=sh 

' change 3 to be the number of static sheets you have in the Workbook.
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Sheets.Count - 3 ' change 3 to the proper number

End Sub
```

Comment: This does exactly as I want, thank you.  would you please suggest how I can name the sheets Master1, Master2 ....).

Comment: @user3266075 You can add any prefix to the name at the second last line.  For `Master` change it to this:  `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Master" & Sheets.Count - 3`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you need to do. Your issue is because you cannot loop in this way without declaring a global variable.

To get what I think you want to do working - first you need to declare a global variable - right at the top of the module:

```
Global iter As Integer
```

iter in this case is just my shorthand for iteration - you can call it whatever you want.

```
    Sub NewSheets()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template")
Set sh = Sheets("Sheets Insert")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

Sheets("Master").Copy After:=sh
If iter = 0 Then
    iter = 1
End If

ActiveSheet.Name = iter
iter = iter + 1

If iter = 20 Then
    iter = 1
End If

End Sub
```

This makes your code easier as you won't need to physically loop.

This changes 0 to 1 for the first ever - then will count adding new sheets until it gets to 20 (bear in mind this wouldn't work for re-using those names)

Comment: I have tried this and it works, the only limitation is if I cant reuse a name even if I have deleted the sheet.